# How to use the twitter object in multiple fragments?

Tags: java, android, twitter, android-fragments, twitter4j

I'm using 'twitter4j' to make a twitter client app. and I want to bypass the Twitter object from the MainActivity.java to different fragments in my app to be used by them. what is the best way to do that?

I don't know if i can do it with 'Bundle' ?!

and when I tried to make a constructor for my fragment for example:
    public Fragment_a(Twitter twitter)
    {
    //
    }
i got a warning from eclipse saying that:
"Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle)"

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the twitter object in your activity, and then just let your fragments grab it

```
twitterObject = ((MyActivity)getActivity()).getTwitterObject();
if (twitterObject != null)
{
    // do something
}
```